# What is the name of this special function?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Consider a special function defined as:

$$f(a_1,a_2,a_3;b_1,b_2,b_3;c;x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3,z_1,z_2,z_3)=\\
=\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3,\\j_1,j_2,j_3,=0\\k_1,k_2,k_3}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_{i_1+i_2+i_3}(a_2)_{j_1+j_2+j_3}(a_3)_{k_1+k_2+k_3}(b_1)_{i_1+j_1+k_1}(b_2)_{i_2+j_2+k_2}(b_3)_{i_3+j_3+k_3}}{i_1!i_2!i_3!j_1!j_2!j_3!k_1!k_2!k_3!(c)_{i_1+i_2+i_3+j_1+j_2+j_3+k_1+k_2+k_3}}\prod_{r=1}^3x_r^{i_r}y_r^{j_r}z_r^{k_r}$$

where $(x)_y=\Gamma(x+y)/\Gamma(x)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Does this function have a name, and if so what is it?

EDIT:

Note for instance a curiosity - for e.g. $a_2,a_3=0$ the function reduces to a [Lauricella function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series):

$$f(a,0,0,b_1,b_2,b_3,c;x_1,x_2,x_3,...) = 
\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{i_1+i_2+i_3} (b_1)_{i_1} (b_2)_{i_2} (b_3)_{i_3}} {(c)_{i_1+i_2+i_3} \,i_1! \,i_2! \,i_3!} \,x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}x_3^{i_3}$$

Comment: If you want Readers to help you determine if this function has a special name in the literature, would it not be a good start to explain the context in which you found or considered this function?

Comment: I found this function when considering certain integrals over gluon scattering amplitudes. So broadly speaking, its origin is in physics / nature.

Comment: Have you looked at the 1954 paper by Shanti Saran, cited in that Wikipedia article?  It seems to me that you have a hypergeometric function that (by using nine variables) generalizes some or all of these Lauricella-Saran hypergeometric functions.  I can check the local university library, if that would help.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your help! It seems that I found the function in the literature. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

After some search I found that this function is actually the so called hypergeometric function of type $(4,8)$. Series and integral definitions can be found around eq. (3.24) in the book  ["Theory of Hypergeometric Functions"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4) by Aomoto and Kita.